# Pullback of k-form under antipodal map

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, pullback

So I want to compute the pull back of $\omega = \frac{R^2}{\sqrt{R^2-u^2-v^2}}du \wedge dv$ under the antipodal map $f: S^2 \to S^2$ where $S^2$ is the a sphere of radisu $R$. Now I am using the hemisphere charts so for the pullback I am working in the chart $U = \{ (x,y,\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 -y^2)}\}$ with map $ \phi (x,y,\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 -y^2})) \to (x,y) = (u,v) $.
So the $z$ coordinate is positive. Then the antipodal map which sends $(x,y,\sqrt{R^2 - x^2-y^2}) \to (-x,-y,- \sqrt{R^2 - x^2-y^2}) $ can be written in coordinates as $(u, v) \to (-u, -v)$
I computed $f^*(\omega) $ as

$f^*(\omega) = (\frac{R^2}{\sqrt{R^2-u^2-v^2}} \circ f(u,v)) \cdot f^*(du) \wedge f^*(dv) = \frac{R^2}{\sqrt{R^2-u^2-v^2}} du \wedge dv $

But apparently I am suppose to get $f^*(\omega) = - \omega$. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, if you compose $\frac{R^2}{\sqrt{R^2-u^2-v^2}}$ with $f$ you get the same thing, and $f^*(du) = du$ and $f^*(dv) = dv$

Originally $\omega = i^*(xdy \wedge dz + y dz \wedge dx + z dx \wedge dy)$ under the inclusion map $i: S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, which I computed in the same chart, I am pretty sure my computation for $\omega$ is correct but I dont know what I am doing wrong... to not get a negative.

Comment: This is an awkward choice of charts to use, as the antipodal map automatically is sending you from one chart to the other. But it's easy to see that for the $2$-form $\omega$ on $\Bbb R^3$, the antipodal map $A$ pulls back $\omega$ to $-\omega$, and therefore $i^*(A^*\omega) = i^*(-\omega)=-i^*\omega$.